# dev express xtra grid removes styling

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

I have an incoming emails grid which is of type XtraGrid.
I have a column called "isRead" which is of type boolean.

```
 Private Sub IsReadEmails_BoldFont()
    'This Sub checks all data and if their column "IsRead" is equal to 0 then will make all this rows font Bold.
    Dim IsRead As Boolean

    For i As Integer = 0 To gridvwIncEmailsList.RowCount
        IsRead = gridvwIncEmailsList.GetRowCellValue(i, gridvwIncEmailsList.Columns(13))
        If Not (IsRead) Then
            gridvwIncEmailsList.SelectRow(i)
            gridvwIncEmailsList.Appearance.SelectedRow.BackColor = Color.White
            gridvwIncEmailsList.Appearance.SelectedRow.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 10.0F, FontStyle.Bold)
            gridvwIncEmailsList.Appearance.SelectedRow.ForeColor = Color.Black

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

This is what treats my grid for my incoming emaisl style.
At a first glance my code works, WHenever my form loads my styling is correct.

Once i click inside my grid all bold items are restored to normal!!
Seems like it does some kind of refresh.
There are no events that listen to the click event.

Why is this happening?
Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to reproduce the issue without getting further details about other `XtraGrid` settings. Are you sure that all grid event handlers set properly (including `RowClick`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the RowStyle event for the XtraGrid: [DevExpress Custom Grid Styles](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114615/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Getting-Started/Walkthroughs/Appearance-and-Conditional-Formatting/Tutorial-Custom-Styles-for-Rows-and-Cells)

```
    Private Sub gridvwIncEmailsList_RowStyle(ByVal sender As Object,
         ByVal e As RowStyleEventArgs) Handles gridvwIncEmailsList.RowStyle
    Dim View As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
    If e.RowHandle >= 0 Then
        Dim IsRead As String = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns("IsRead"))
       If IsRead = "Unchecked" Then
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightCoral)
            e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.White
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White
           e.Appearance.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 10.0F, FontStyle.Bold)
            e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How do i have to call this sub?

I try: gridvwIncEmailsList_RowStyle(gridvwIncEmailsList, e)

And i get the following error: ": 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs'.'"

Comment: As stated here: https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.RowStyle.event The RowStyle event is raised for individual data or group rows before they are repainted. The appearance settings of the data and group rows are specified by the GridViewAppearances.Row and GridViewAppearances.GroupRow properties, respectively. Handle this event to override the appearance settings of individual rows.

Comment: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs'.'

Comment: Your answer is almost correct, just fix these 3 things.
1.  "Private Sub gridvwIncEmailsList_RowStyle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RowStyleEventArgs) Handles gridvwIncEmailsList.RowStyle"                                                                           


 2. Dim IsRead As String = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns("IsRead"))

            3.If IsRead = "Unchecked" Then

Comment: Good catch. Updated!

Comment: I am sorry. Fix this too.   -----  e.Appearance.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 10.0F, FontStyle.Bold)

Comment: Approved your changes.